# Filter out 0 outbound value transaction from etherscan

Tags: python, ethereum, blockchain, etherscan

I'm working on a small project - A plot of historical tokens amount in ETH address. I'm using Python and etherscan API https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/accounts

My test subject is a random address -
I got all the transactions of all the tokens, But the end balance does not match the balance the address currently has. There is a post about it - https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26521/why-is-my-balance-not-equal-to-the-sum-of-inbound-minus-the-sum-of-outbound-and but it not answering my question because it is without an API request.

The main problem is that in the response, I don't see any data indicating contract transactions or outbound value.

I will show you an example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBUSb.jpg)

As we can see, there are eight transactions, and the sum of all of them is 39285968212.878494 (column value2). But the actual balance in the address 0x4c8CFE078a5B989CeA4B330197246ceD82764c63 is 29129061769, which is exactly the one transaction I colored in yellow. So from my understanding, I need to find a way to filter the other seven transactions from the data. But I don't know how, I would appreciate any help.

I tried to look for some information about it online but didn't find any thing useful.

Comment: So you want to look at all transactions of some account and keep only those that are reflected in balance, right?

Comment: Yes this is correct

Comment: @SUTerliakov Yes. Do you know how to do it?